# Why is the imagine not displayed while beeing "inline". js/html

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to show and hide a picture by using one button. when it's clicked, the picture is displayed and a variable is set to 1. so that when you press the button the next time, the picture will be hidden again.
After the button is pressed, I console.log the value of set variable + if the picture is displayed or not. Console says that the Picture is "inline". But the picture is not on my screen.
I think all you need is the js function. If you need more information. just comment. thank's!

```js
    <script>
       
       function showHideM(){
            let open;
            open = 0
            if (open == 0){
                open = 1;
                document.getElementById("melmanId").style.display = "inline"; 
                console.log(open)
                console.log(document.getElementById("melmanId").style.display)
return;
            }
            if (open == 1){
                    open = 0;
                    document.getElementById("melmanId").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: You show and hide it directly. Both conditions are met at the time they get checked.

Comment: I tried to "return" at the end of the if (open == 0) statement, so that the image doesn't get hidden as soon as it's shown. Now it show's the image but doesn't hide again. whats my fault? thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need flags to maintain the state of the image's visibility. You can use [`classList`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method to toggle a class on/off or, in this case, visible/hidden, which makes things a little easier.

```js
// Cache the elements, and add an event listener
// to the button
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Toggle the "hidden" class
function handleClick() {
  img.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
img { display: block; margin-bottom: 1em; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #fffff0; }
```

```html
<img class="hidden" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
<button>Click</button>
```

Additional documentation

- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: that works. but I am new to programming and haven't worked with jquery yet. so this doesn't do the job for me, since I want to understand the code. thank's tho

Comment: Er, this isn't jQuery. This is native JS. @AnsG

Comment: saw "query" and thought it was the same as Jquery. so sorry

Comment: I've added links to the MDN documentation that might help you understand.

Comment: don't know if one should thank someone on stackoverflow since it says " Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post" . But thank you.

Comment: No problem @AnsG. Keep [the link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) bookmarked as it will come in very useful during your coding sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this will replace all the styles applied to 'melmanId'

```
<script>
 let show = true;
 function showHideM() {
    show = !show;
    if(show){
        document.getElementById("melmanId").style.display = "inline";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("melmanId").style.display = "none";
    }
 }
</script>
```